# Parameterising a tricky ellipsoid

Tags: surface-integrals, greens-theorem

I have an ellipsoid $$x^{2}+2y^{2}+4z^{2}=18$$ which lies right to the plane y=1 and has outward pointing orientation.

I am asked to use stoke's theorem to find $$\oint_{C} F\cdot dr = \iint_{R}\nabla \times FdS$$

but to do so a parameterisation is required such that I can express x, y and z in terms of 2 variables (I.e., u and v).

I begin first by finding the boundary C of S. To do so, I sub y =1 into the equation of the given ellipsoid. we get

$$x^{2}+4z^{2}=16$$

Edit: Aware of the standard parametrisation used in spherical and cylindrical coordiantes but unsure how I should apply these to this problem.
Give me a kick

Comment: There is standard parametrization: $x=\sqrt{18}\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=3\sin\theta\sin\phi$, $z=\sqrt{9/2}\cos\theta$. Why you don't want to use it?

Comment: I have made the parametrisation x = Cos(t) and z = 2Sin(t) but my solution states z to be z = -2Sin(t). Why is there a negative?